# C++ passing an object to a function, the operator= is not called

Tags: visual-c++

So here is the code snippet:

> class MyClass { public:   MyClass(char chIn)  {       std::cout <<
>   "Constructor!" << std::endl;  }
>
> MyClass & operator= (char chIn)     {       std::cout << "Assigment
>   operator!" << std::endl;  } } ;
>
> void Func(MyClass objIn) {    return; }
>
> int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) {    Func('T');  system("PAUSE");
>     return 0; }

In the upper example the constructor of the object is called!!!! Why is this behavior? Shouldn't the assigment operator be called? Because we're assigning a value to the function parameter, aren't we?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

operator= invoked for already existent object otherwise constructor(or copy constructor) is used to create needed instance

Comment: But isn't the function parameter already existent object. I mean isn't it created before the value to be assigned to it?

Comment: @sasho648 No it isn't. It is created once the function is called.

Comment: Using the value that must be assigned to it (passed to it)???? But this is unwise. In this case we can't pass multiple arguments to its constructor if we don't create our object with them and after that pass it at once. The assigment operator always have one argument, so it would be more logical it to be called after the object is constructed.